# WebBrowser Login Box

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a webrowser inside my Windows Form Application, I navigate to certain address (ex. 10.185.106.25).  When navigating to the specific address, a "Windows Security" login box appears, asking for username and password.

Now I want to automate logging in with the credentials needed. This form will be navigating to different addresses throughout it's process, but won't always need the credentials entered depending where it navigates to.

Now, this "Windows Security" Login box does not appear in the Windows Task Manager, meaning it is part of my WebBrowser in my Windows Form Application.

Is there a way to know when this "Windows Security" box appears.  Is there some way to know this happened. Is this event?  Any explination of how to handle this login box existing would great.

I'm not sure how to handle this inside a Windows Form Application.

Comment: It's handled by the browser, but depending on your ASP.NET framework, there are different places for you to handle security.

Comment: I know I'm using the .NET framework 4, I'm assuming that applies to the ASP.NET framework also? If so, how do I go about handeling the security?

Comment: Web Forms or MVC? If you're just learning for yourself (not school or your job), you'd be best suited by using C# and MVC as both Web Forms and VB support in ASP.NET [are being dropped in ASP.NET 5](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/24/top-10-changes-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6) (Visual Studio 2015 with .NET 5.0).

Comment: I'm creating a windows form application using VB .net for my job using the .NET framework .4.  I have a webrowser in my windows form application in which I navigate to different addresses. Some of the addresses cause the "Windows Security" login box to appear. I would like to know when that login box appears.

Comment: OK. With this being native to a WinForms project, that changes how everything is handled. Please add that information to your question, and add the WinForms tag.

Comment: Edited and added proper tag, Thanks!

Comment: Please [do not include tags in your question's title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).